# Adding a button to stop the timer in the React documentation clock example

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

So i'm following this tutorial from the React documentation to make a Clock

https://es.reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

My problem is that when i try to add a button to stop the clock i get two errors.

When i put () when calling the function after clicking the button my clock stops alone after one second without even clicking it.

When i don't put the parenthesis when calling the function in the event i get this error

"Cannot read property 'timerID' of undefined"

```js
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class Clock extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { date: new Date() };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerID = setInterval(() => this.tick(), 1000);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerID);
  }

  tick() {
    this.setState({ date: new Date() });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello People</h1>
        <h2>This is a beautiful clock</h2>
        <h3>It is {this.state.date.toLocaleTimeString()}.</h3>
        <button onClick={this.componentWillUnmount}>Stop clock</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Clock date={new Date()}></Clock>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

What coult be the problem?

Comment: The reason the function is being invoked when you include the parentheses is because the parentheses indicates you want to immediately invoke the function when this code runs, and in this case that is upon first rendering.

Answer (score 1):

`componentWillUnmount` is a special lifecycle function that you shouldn't be calling directly.

Make a separate function called something like `handleStopClick` and in that function, call `clearInterval`.

Then the button will be
`<button onClick={this.handleStopClick}>Stop click</button>`

Comment: Thanks!!  Do you know ehre i can find more info about the componentWillUnmount function?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillunmount